# SWI-Prolog: Syntax error: Operator expected

Tags: syntax, prolog, syntax-error

I'm building something for the university and I'm getting the following error:
ERROR: [Thread pce] path/diagnosis.pl:6:3: Syntax error: Operator expected
I looked at the line 6 but I have no idea what's wrong. I tried removing the space, changing the variable name, reindenting, nothing works.
Here's an image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69RIl.png)
Here's the code:

```
% This buffer is for notes you don't want to save.
% If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
% then enter the text in that file's own buffer.
domains
    Disease,indication = symbol
    Patient,name = string
predicates
    hypothesis(string,disease)
    symptom(name,indication)
    response(char)
    go
clauses
go :-
    write("What is the patient's name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.

go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.
```

Comment: That's Turbo Prolog.

Comment: Try removing everything above the first line that says `go :-`.